# Transform Java List into the Pivot format

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, java-stream

I have a below class and would like to transform the list of data objects into the pivot table format with java.

```
public class Data {

    private String consultedOn;
    private String consultedBy;

    // Getters

    // Setters


}


List<Data> reports = new ArrayList<Data>();

reports.add(new Data("04/12/2018","Mr.Bob"));
reports.add(new Data("04/12/2018","Mr.Jhon"));
reports.add(new Data("04/12/2018","Mr.Bob"));
reports.add(new Data("05/12/2018","Mr.Jhon"));
reports.add(new Data("06/12/2018","Mr.Bob"));
reports.add(new Data("06/12/2018","Mr.Jhon"));
reports.add(new Data("07/12/2018","Mr.Bob"));
```

I would like to transform the above list into the below table format with java within a collection.

```
consultedOn       Mr.Bob          Mr.Jhon  
---------------------------------------
04/12/2018           2              1
05/12/2018           0              1
06/12/2018           1              1
07/12/2018           1              0
```

Note that the consultedOn field is not restricted to two values, this field may contain any data so that the collection should be dynamic.

I tried using Java8 streams with below code.

```
class DataMap {


 private String consultedOn;
    private String consultedBy;

    public DataMap(String consultedOn) {
        super();
        this.consultedOn = consultedOn;
    }

    public DataMap(String consultedOn, String consultedBy) {
        super();
        this.consultedOn = consultedOn;
        this.consultedBy = consultedBy;
    }


    public String getConsultedOn() {
        return consultedOn;
    }


    public void setConsultedOn(String consultedOn) {
        this.consultedOn = consultedOn;
    }


    public String getConsultedBy() {
        return consultedBy;
    }


    public void setConsultedBy(String consultedBy) {
        this.consultedBy = consultedBy;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((consultedOn == null) ? 0 : consultedOn.hashCode());
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof DataMap ))
            return false;
        DataMap other = (DataMap )obj;
        if (consultedOn == null) {
            if (other.consultedOn != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!consultedOn.equals(other.consultedOn))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}


Map<DataMap, List<DataReport>> map = reports.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> new DataMap(x.getConsultedOn(), x.getConsultedBy())));
```

But the map is not giving intend results as per my expectations.

I'm not sure how to go-ahead  with this kind of data, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes indeed I tried with java8 streams

Comment: Start by designing a class Row representing a row of your result. It has a consultedOn, and a number of consultation by person. So it should have a field consultedOn, and a Map<String, Integer> containing the number of consultations for each person for that date. You want one instance of that class for each date, so you'll need a Map<String, Row>.

Comment: @isudarsan I made an edit to the question https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53682421/3 . I hope that makes it much clean to read and understand. Do review and let me know if that doesn't change the intent of the question anyhow or you can also *Rollback* to that version under revisions if you find it apt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a complete answer, using the technique I explained in the comment, i.e. design a class `Row` representing what you want to generate for each row, i.e. a `consultedOn` string, and a number of consultations for each person.

```
public class Pivot {
    private static final class Data {

        private final String consultedOn;
        private final String consultedBy;

        public Data(String consultedOn, String consultedBy) {
            this.consultedOn = consultedOn;
            this.consultedBy = consultedBy;
        }

        public String getConsultedOn() {
            return consultedOn;
        }

        public String getConsultedBy() {
            return consultedBy;
        }
    }

    private static final class Row {
        private final String consultedOn;
        private final Map<String, Integer> consultationsByPerson = new HashMap<>();

        public Row(String consultedOn) {
            this.consultedOn = consultedOn;
        }

        public void addPerson(String person) {
            consultationsByPerson.merge(person, 1, Integer::sum);
        }

        public int getConsultationsFor(String person) {
            return consultationsByPerson.getOrDefault(person, 0);
        }

        public String getConsultedOn() {
            return consultedOn;
        }
    }

    private static class PivotReport {

        private final Map<String, Row> rowsByConsultedOn = new HashMap<>();
        private SortedSet<String> persons = new TreeSet<>();

        private PivotReport() {}

        private void addData(Data d) {
            rowsByConsultedOn.computeIfAbsent(d.getConsultedOn(), Row::new).addPerson(d.getConsultedBy());
            persons.add(d.consultedBy);
        }

        public static PivotReport create(List<Data> list) {
            PivotReport report = new PivotReport();
            list.forEach(report::addData);
            return report;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String headers = "Consulted on\t" + String.join("\t", persons);
            String rows =  rowsByConsultedOn.values()
                                            .stream()
                                            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Row::getConsultedOn))
                                            .map(this::rowToString)
                                            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            return headers + "\n" + rows;
        }

        private String rowToString(Row row) {
            return row.getConsultedOn() + "\t" +
                persons.stream()
                       .map(person -> Integer.toString(row.getConsultationsFor(person)))
                       .collect(Collectors.joining("\t"));
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Data> list = createListOfData();
        PivotReport report = PivotReport.create(list);
        System.out.println(report);
    }

    private static List<Data> createListOfData() {
        List<Data> reports = new ArrayList<Data>();

        reports.add(new Data("04/12/2018","Mr.Bob"));
        reports.add(new Data("04/12/2018","Mr.Jhon"));
        reports.add(new Data("04/12/2018","Mr.Bob"));
        reports.add(new Data("05/12/2018","Mr.Jhon"));
        reports.add(new Data("06/12/2018","Mr.Bob"));
        reports.add(new Data("06/12/2018","Mr.Jhon"));
        reports.add(new Data("07/12/2018","Mr.Bob"));
        reports.add(new Data("07/12/2018","Mr.Smith"));

        return reports;
    }
}
```

Note that since you're using String instead of LocalDate for the `consultedOn` field, the dates will be sorted lexicographically instead of being sorted chronologically. You should use the appropriate type: LocalDate.

Comment: @isudarsan it will, but that's not what matters. Do you understand it? Do you understand how using the appropriate class to represent what you want helps producing the result?

Comment: yes @JB Nizet, Thanks very much . I understood completely.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking to use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) to group the `List<DataMap>` by `consultedOn` and further grouping it by `consultedBy` attribute and their count as :

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> finalMapping = reports.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DataMap::getConsultedOn,
            Collectors.groupingBy(DataMap::getConsultedBy,Collectors.counting())));
```

This would provide you as an output:

> ```
> {05/12/2018={Mr.Jhon=1}, 06/12/2018={Mr.Jhon=1, Mr.Bob=1},
> 07/12/2018={Mr.Bob=1}, 04/12/2018={Mr.Jhon=1, Mr.Bob=2}}
> ```

Further, if you require all the corresponding `consultedBy` values to be accounted in, you can create a `Set` of those from the initial `List<DataMap>` as :

```
Set<String> consultedBys = reports.stream()
        .map(DataMap::getConsultedBy)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

using which you can modify your existing map obtained to contain 0 count as well in the following manner:

```
finalMapping.forEach((k, v) -> consultedBys.forEach(c -> v.putIfAbsent(c, 0L)));
```

This would now provide you as the output:

> ```
> {05/12/2018={Mr.Jhon=1, Mr.Bob=0}, 06/12/2018={Mr.Jhon=1, Mr.Bob=1},
> 07/12/2018={Mr.Jhon=0, Mr.Bob=1}, 04/12/2018={Mr.Jhon=1, Mr.Bob=2}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The other would be like this:

```
Map<Pair<String, String>, Integer> map = reports
      .stream()
     .collect(toMap(data -> new Pair<>(data.getConsultedOn(),
                    data.getConsultedBy()), data -> 1, Integer::sum));

Map<String, DataMap> result= new HashMap<>();
```

-

```
class DataMap {
   private String consultedOn;
   private Map<String, Integer> map;
}
```

-

```
Set<String> persons = new HashSet<>();
persons = reports.stream().map(Data::getConsultedBy).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

-

```
for (Map.Entry<Pair<String, String>, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      Map<String, Integer> val = new HashMap<>();
      for (String person : persons) {
          if (!person.equals(entry.getKey().getValue()))
              val.put(person, 0);
           else
              val.put(entry.getKey().getValue(), entry.getValue());
       }
        result.put(entry.getKey().getKey(), new DataMap(entry.getKey().getKey(), val));
}
```

and final result:

```
List<DataMap> finalResult = new ArrayList<>(result.values());
```

Comment: Its worth mentioning that `Pair` either has to be implemented or imported from an external library.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a separate data structure, you can use a Map of key as consultedOn (date or String) and have the value as a list of (String or your own defined POJO with overridden equals() method.Here in I have used a map like `Map<String, List<String>>`

All you need is the two methods:
one to set report (addDataToReport) : for each consultedOn (key), create a list of doctors consulted . See comments for map.merge usage

and one to display the data in a report manner (printReport). We are using "%10s" to give proper formatting. Instead of println, format doesn't implicitly append a new line character

Moreover to get the report's column we need to have a set (unique value list), `doctors.add(consultedBy);` will serve us for this purpose . Java will take care of keeping the doctors' value unique.

```
public class Application {
    Set<String> doctors = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    private void addDataToReport(Map<String, List<String>> reportMap, String consultedOn, String consultedBy) {
        doctors.add(consultedBy); // set the doctors Set
        reportMap.merge(consultedOn, Arrays.asList(consultedBy)// if key = consultedOn is not there add , a new list
                , (v1, v2) -> Stream.concat(v1.stream(), v2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()));//else merge previous and new values , here concatenate two lists
    }

    private void printReport(Map<String, List<String>> reportMap) {
        /*Set Headers*/
        String formatting = "%10s";//give a block of 10 characters for each string to print
        System.out.format(formatting, "consultedOn");
        doctors.forEach(t -> System.out.format(formatting, t));// print data on console without an implicit new line
        System.out.println("\n---------------------------------------");
        /*Set row values*/
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : reportMap.entrySet()) {
            Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            doctors.forEach(t -> map.put(t, 0)); // initialise each doctor count on a day to 0
            entry.getValue().forEach(t -> map.put(t, map.get(t) + 1));
            System.out.format(formatting, entry.getKey());
            map.values().forEach(t -> System.out.format(formatting, t));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        Map<String, List<String>> reportMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        String MR_JHON = "Mr.Jhon";
        String MR_BOB = "Mr.Bob ";
        application.addDataToReport(reportMap, "04/12/2018", MR_BOB);
        application.addDataToReport(reportMap, "04/12/2018", MR_JHON);
        application.addDataToReport(reportMap, "04/12/2018", MR_BOB);
        application.addDataToReport(reportMap, "05/12/2018", MR_JHON);
        application.addDataToReport(reportMap, "06/12/2018", MR_BOB);
        application.addDataToReport(reportMap, "06/12/2018", MR_JHON);
        application.addDataToReport(reportMap, "07/12/2018", MR_BOB);
        application.printReport(reportMap);
    }
}
```

Result

```
consultedOn   Mr.Bob    Mr.Jhon
---------------------------------------
04/12/2018         2         1
05/12/2018         0         1
06/12/2018         1         1
07/12/2018         1         0
```